# Is it possible to achieve bi-directional sync between excel and MongoDB?

Tags: python, excel, mongodb

A friend of mine has a team of data collectors that collect data in excel, he needs it to be updated in his `MongoDb` database in real time, if that's complex, he wants it to be done in a single click.

I tried writing a program that checks the file and the DB to constantly update them, I'm a beginner when it comes to programming so it looked like this

```
import pandas as pd
from motor import MotorClient


client = MotorClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['Exceldb']
collection = db['excel']

#Excel read
excel_file = "Employee.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(excel_file)


collection.drop()  # Drop existing data if any
collection.insert_many(df.to_dict('records')) 

data = list(collection.find())
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(excel_file, index=False)
client.close()
```

When I ran this, nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data you need is there and path to the file is correct.

MotorClient is from the motor library, which is for asynchronous IO.
Your code doesn’t use any of the features of motor.

Try pymongo
change stream can access real-time changes.